# Caret GBM predict only produces 106 outputs while newdata has 403 rows... What's up?

Tags: boosting, caret

I am training ML classifiers using caret to predict mortality in a clinical data set. Training with caret's gbm works well, but when I try to use predict, I get very strange results. Here is my code:

```
set.seed (234)

fitControl <- trainControl (method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 5, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

gbmGrid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth = c(3, 4, 5, 6),
                    n.trees = (1:6)*100, 
                    shrinkage = c(0.001, 0.005, 0.01),
                    n.minobsinnode = c(8, 10,15,20))

gbmFit <- train (Dead ~ ., data = df.use, method = "gbm", metric = "ROC", maximize = TRUE, trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid = gbmGrid, na.action = na.pass, verbose = FALSE)

predict (gbmFit, newdata = df.use, n.trees = 400)
```

The results are:

```
 [1] FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE.
 [15] FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE.
 [29] FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE.
 [43] FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE.
 [57] FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. TRUE. 
 [71] TRUE.  TRUE.  FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. TRUE.  TRUE.  TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE.
 [85] FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. TRUE.  TRUE. 
 [99] FALSE. TRUE.  FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE. FALSE.
Levels: FALSE. TRUE.
```

This is 106 values, while df.use has dimensions (403 x 46). Here are the types for each variable in df.use, "Dead" is the outcome to predict:

```
                           Name    KClass
1                           Age   numeric
2                           Sex    factor
3                     Anion.gap   numeric
4                        Sodium   numeric
5                     Potassium   numeric
6                      Chloride   numeric
7                           CO2   numeric
8                    Creatinine   numeric
9                           ALT   numeric
10                          AST   numeric
11                     Alk.phos   numeric
12              Total.bilirubin   numeric
13                      Calcium   numeric
14                      Albumin   numeric
15                          Hgb   numeric
16                          MCV   numeric
17                          RDW   numeric
18                          Plt   numeric
19               Neutrophil.Abs   numeric
20               Lymphocyte.Abs   numeric
21                 Monocyte.Abs   numeric
22 Lactate..venous.or.arterial.   numeric
23                   Troponin.T   numeric
24                  Weight..kg.   numeric
25                           HR   numeric
26                  Temperature   numeric
27                           RR   numeric
28                         SpO2   numeric
29                    Bilateral    factor
30                          MAP   numeric
31                          AMS    factor
32                        Cough    factor
33                  FeverChills    factor
34                     Headache    factor
35                         Cold    factor
36                      Dyspnea    factor
37                       Throat    factor
38                           GI    factor
39                      Myalgia    factor
40                          HTN    factor
41                           DM    factor
42                          CAD    factor
43                          CKD    factor
44                          HIV    factor
45                   AsthmaCOPD    factor
46                         Dead    factor
```

During training there are no warnings or errors. But it simply doesn't predict all the outcomes. What might be going wrong? Thank you!

(*Note:* I know it's bad to use the same data for training and for testing (prediction), I'm doing this just for this example and to figure out how gbm predict works.)

Comment: Maybe you have `NA`. Without a reproducible example it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Realized I had na.action = na.pass in my training, but I did not have na.action = na.pass in my call to predict. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Best of luck with the rest of your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use na.action = na.pass in predict(), as I did in training the model. Thanks user11852.